# How to jump to non-matching records in Excel?

Tags: excel

Typically when I want to find non-matching rows, I'll use conditional formatting or a simple if statement like `=IF(A1=B1,"","MISMATCH")`. However, I have a file that is too large to comfortably scroll through, so I thought to use the ctrl+down arrow trick to jump to each "MISMATCH" instance. However, that doesn't work, presumably because there's a formula in each cell. So I thought I'd copy the column and paste values only, but that doesn't work either. It just jumps me down to the very last row.

Any advice about how to jump to the instances where column A =/= column B or otherwise get a list of the rows where that is the case?

Comment: How about using Filter and only show the ones with `MISMATCH`

Comment: Oh dear, that's such an easy solution! I got so frustrated by the paste-values not working that my brain just shut off. Thanks. :)

Comment: Or just filter NULL cells then delete them, and after that remove filter to use ctrl + down arrow that you mention to see all the values in the table